# UnityTeams: Files to publish but no Upload button

Tags: unity, architecture, file, filesystem, teamwork

I am using Unity 2019.2.14f1 to build a game.

As I am working with a team, we have decided to use Unity Teams for the collaboration.

The project escalated and we ended up having to architecture a different project structure, directories and files.

Due to that, I created standard folders, deleted others, moved files.

Changes were made, the project was saved and now I see the blue icon in the majority of folders and lots of items in the Project Folder.

[image: Unity Teams - Project folder]

If I look at the Collab button on the top right corner of the screen and hover the mouse it appears the message:

> You have files to publish

[image: Unity Teams - Files to publish]

However, if I press the button, even though it shows the blue icon, that shows that I have files to upload, it appears:

> You are up to date!

[image: Unity Teams - Up to date]

This is the first time I saw this problem.

I have done some changes to one of the scenes to see if the problem disappeared, however it persists.

I have been waiting for quite some time now, and decided to ask you for some guidance.

Everything is fine with the network connection.

In this particular situation, the log system that will appear when I upload the files is going to be huge. Is this be the reason behind the problem? What shall I do to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My first step was letting the team know that I was having this problem to prevent them from working on the project for a while.

Then rebooted Unity, as this was an internal bug [I also reported the situation to Unity].

That solved my problem - classic IT solution.

I was afraid of losing all the data and changes and didn't thought that the files are saved locally.